# Syntax Error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have received data from backend which contains a `student` object.

The `student` contains a field named `grade`. I would like to explicitly update that value of the `student` object in my code:

```
// the component parses the student object, I don't show those code here

useEffect(() => {
    const {grade} = calculateNewGrade(student);
    // Syntax Error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression
    student?.grade = grade;
  }, [student]);
```

When I run my app, I ended up with error "Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression" for the code showed above. Why? What is the correct way to update that value then?

**=== About using the optional syntax `student?.grade` ===**

The reason why I use optional syntax is that the `student` at the beginning is undefined or null until it is loaded. If I remove the optional `?` I would end up with another error "undefined is not an object" when evaluating `student.grade`.

Comment: @SuperStormer please see my update, I explained why using optional syntax.

Comment: you can't just wrap the whole thing inside an `if (student) { const {grade} .... } ` ?

Comment: *"the student at the beginning is undefined or null until it is loaded"* And what would you expect to happen if you try to assign to `student?.grade` when `student` is `null`? Should it silently skip the assignment? Should it populate `student` with a new object?  Optional chaining is for *accessing* properties, not assigning to them.

Comment: try with student!

Comment: @Thiluxan that's typescript (non-null assertion operator), not javascript.

Comment: @CallumMorrisson The question is on typescript right?

Comment: no, javascript it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optional chaining should be used when reading the value, not when assigning it. You can update the piece of code to this:

```
if (student != null) {
    student.grade = grade;
}
```

Edit: Mistake pointed out by Felix King

Comment: I think it should just be `if (student)`. Currently you are only assigning to `student.grade` if `student.grade` is already set.

Comment: You should probably provide a reference why optional chaining is for retrieval only.